# How to solve this differential equation when it has a series in it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation since I'm trying to solve for r(z)=r:

$\frac {d^2r(z)}{dz^2} = \frac {klr^{l-1}} {(n + kr^l)}$

And below is my partial solution:

$\frac {d^2r}{dz^2} = {klr^{l-1}} {(n + kr^l)}^{-1}$

$\frac {d^2r}{dz^2} = \frac{klr^{l-1}}{n} {(1 + \frac{kr^l}{n})}^{-1}$

$\frac {d^2r}{dz^2} = \frac{klr^{l-1}}{n} {\sum_{m}(-1)^m (\frac {kr^l}{n})^m }$

$\frac {d^2r}{dz^2} = \frac{kl}{n} {\sum_{m}(-1)^m (\frac {k}{n})^m (r^{lm+l-1})}$

And this is the part where I'm stuck. The first part of my solution had the goal of trying to move r(z) or remove any r from the denominator so that I could solve the differential equation. But that's all I've been able to do because I'm not sure how to solve it since it has a series that has to be solved with the differential equation. I'm pretty lost with solving this part.

*Side note - This condition cannot be applied: ($\frac {kr}{n} << 1$)

Comment: Is it a coincidence that $\frac{klr^{l-1}}{(n + kr^l)}=\frac{d}{dr}\log(n+kr^l)$?

Comment: That's actually a good observation although you missed multiplying the l on the LHS for it to be equal to RHS so it's actually:

$\frac{lklr^{l-1}}{n+kr^l} =\frac{d}{dr} \log(n+kr^l)$

Comment: No, the $l$ is already there between $k$ and $r^{l-1}$.

Comment: Oh right, yes sorry. It's been a long day. I'll look into that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

***Not a solution***

$$\frac {d^2r(z)}{dz^2} = \frac {klr^{l-1}} {(n + kr^l)}$$
$$r''r' = \frac {r'klr^{l-1}} {(n + kr^l)}$$
$$\frac12(r'^2)=\int \frac {r'klr^{l-1}} {(n + kr^l)}dz$$
$$\frac12(r'^2)=\int \frac {klr^{l-1}} {(n + kr^l)}dr$$
$$\frac12(r'^2)=\int \frac {du}{u} \text { ,where } u=(n + kr^l)$$
$$(r'^2)=2\ln|(n + kr^l)|+K$$
$$r'=\pm \sqrt{2\ln|(n + kr^l)|+K}$$
Not that easy to solve indeed...

Comment: Yeah, I was trying it out after checking what you did and picked up from where you left off and was stuck in the integrating once more.

Comment: Yes thats not easy...@KathKiyan